# Implementing this with CSS and HTMl

Tags: html, css, center, html-lists

This is my css -

```
#nav {  
    position: relative;  
    background-color: #292929;  
    float: left;
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}  
#nav li {  
    float: left;  
    list-style: none;  

    width:auto;

}  
#nav li a {  
    color: #e3e3e3;  
    position: relative;  
    z-index: 2;  
    float: left;  

}
ul, li {  
  margin:0;
    padding: 0; 

} 

#blob {  

    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    z-index : 1;  
    background: #0b2b61;  


    background-repeat:repeat;

}
```

I want to place this object in the center. How do i do that. I also want the background to fit the page. I tried a lot, but it isn't working.

```
<ul id="nav">  
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You want the list items to be centered in a horizontal navigation? Kinda confused on what the result should be. =/.

Answer (score 1):

Place an object in the center:
CSS:

```
.Center1
    {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    }

.Center2
{
position:relative;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1024px;
height:800px;
text-align:left;
}
```

Markup:

```
<body class="body">
<div class="Center1">
    <div class="Center2">
                 <!-- Your content -->
```

Comment: that should work if you want to center your webpage (works on IE and FF at least).

Comment: Note that on IE browsers at least using auto to center things doesn't always work unless your ddocument is in standards mode. Make sure it has a valid doctype. <!DOCTYPE html> will probably work if you don't have an exsiting one.

Comment: ah yes I was missing the doc type tag. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You want place `<li>` int the center, right?

The easiest way according to your current markup is to apply fixed `width` and add `margin: 0 auto;` to your li.

Semantics of that solution is really bad, but i guess you don't really care.